# Error While Trying To Insert A SQL Azure Database Table Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure, azure-sql-database

I had a table called 'MyTestTable' in my SQL Azure database.  Using the SQL Azure user interface on it's web page, I renamed the table to 'MyTestTables'.  Now when I run an insert into the table I get the error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TR_MyTestTable_InsertUpdateDelete, Line 8
Invalid object name 'MyDb.MyTestTable'.
```

So, it appears that there's an underlying system stored proc (*edit: looks like it's actually a trigger*) that gets fired during inserts, and the user interface didn't update this stored proc with the new table name.  I tried dropping the table and re-adding it, but the error remains.  After re-adding it, it actually automatically picked up all of the columns the table originally contained, so dropping the table must still keep a reference to it, which gets reused if you re-add it, which is probably why my error is still there.

I can't find this procedure anywhere to modify it.  What can I do to fix this other than creating a new table with a different name?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way.

```
exec  sp_helptext N'MyDB.TR_MyTestTable_InsertUpdateDelete'
```

Gives me the definition.  It's in a format though that can't be copied and pasted.  So I retyped it all and updated the table name and changed it to an alter trigger.  All is good now.

Thanks